# VBA SUMIFs getting confused about dates - producing incorrect result

Tags: vba, date

The below code is producing the wrong result. On the work sheet we are using two identical date formats (dd/mm/yyyy) however when the following is run it appears to be trying to interpret the **rev_date** as American date format, whilst interpreting **grid_date** as the correct UK format.

We tested this by changing the rev_date on the worksheet to the American format, in which case it produces the correct result.

Any ideas why we would need to change rev_date to an American format, we would prefer to keep it as UK?

```
Public Function GRIDSALES(rev_date As Date, grid_date As Date) As Double


  Dim Order_Type As Range
  Dim Final_Price As Range
  Dim PaidAlt As Range
  Dim Excl_Rev As Range
  Dim PAmount1 As Range
  Dim PMethod1 As Range
  Dim PAmount2 As Range
  Dim PayDate2 As Range
  Dim PMethod2 As Range
  Dim Vstatus As Range
  Dim Team As Range

  Application.Volatile (True)

  Set Order_Type = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$D:$D")
  Set Final_Price = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$H:$H")
  Set PaidAlt = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$I:$I")
  Set Excl_Rev = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$K:$K")
  Set PAmount1 = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$O:$O")
  Set First_PD = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$Q:$Q")
  Set PMethod1 = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$R:$R")
  Set PAmount2 = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$T:$T")
  Set PayDate2 = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$V:$V")
  Set PMethod2 = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$W:$W")
  Set Vstatus = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$DL:$DL")
  Set Team = Sheets("KRONOS").Range("$DO:$DO")

            GRIDSALES1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs( _
            PAmount1 _
            , Team, "<>9" _
            , Vstatus, "<>rejected", Vstatus, "<>unverified" _
            , Excl_Rev, "<>1" _
            , PMethod1, "<>Credit" _
            , PMethod1, "<>Amendment" _
            , PMethod1, "<>Pre-paid" _
            , First_PD, ">=" & rev_date _
            , First_PD, "<=" & Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(grid_date, 0))

            GRIDSALES = GRIDSALES1
```

End Function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do this

```
First_PD, ">=" & rev_date
```

and this

```
First_PD, "<=" & Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(grid_date, 0))
```

you are implicitly coercing two variables of type `Date` (`rev_date` and `grid_date`) into type `String`. Implicit coercion is bad practice, and this is a pretty typical example why it's bad practice. Your dates should be explicitly converted to `String` using an unambiguous format, e.g.

```
First_PD, ">=" & Format$(rev_date,"dd mmm yyyy")
```

In this format, 12 Jan 2011 can't be confused with 1 Dec 2011.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of exactly why the date format changes but from googling in the past I am fairly certain that VBA will interpret a date as American which may be the issue.

In your function, could you take each date and try and format to UK date format? Example:

```
Public Function GRIDSALES(rev_date As Date, grid_date As Date) As Double

Dim d1 as Date, d2 as Date

d1 = CDate(Format(rev_date, "dd-mm-yyyy"))
d2 = CDate(Format(grid_date, "dd-mm-yyyy"))

///rest of your code here...

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for this, although they both work I've selected the one above as the main answers. It's probably slightly easier.

Comment: @James: No problem. Glad you got something that worked out for your scenario

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, my error was just that.

But i solved it like this

```
fil1 = "<=" & Month(rev_date) & "/" & Day(rev_date) & "/" & Year(rev_date)
```